# How to write a Function to scan & remove similar words from a large variable using PHP?

Tags: php, function, duplicates

I was trying to generate keywords using dynamic data & hence thought this function could be useful for others hence i have answered the question myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function named scan_dups:

```
function scan_dups($value){
    $end = implode(', ',array_unique(explode(', ', $value)));
echo $end;
    }
```

Now when using, just put all your values inside a variable and put that variable inside this function.
Eg:

```
$a = "a,b,c,d,e,g,f,g,g,s,d,gt,te,h,a";
echo scan_dups($a);
```

And the output would be:

> a,b,c,d,e,g,f,s,gt,te,h